# Refactor Linq to SQL Select Expression

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Linq to SQL statement with a very lengthy select list

```
List<MyClass> myClasses = (from table1 in context.Table1
                          join table2 in context.Table2
                          on table1.Key equals table2.Key
                          join table3 in context.Table3
                          on table1.FK equals table3.Key
                          select new MyClass()
                          {
                            propertyA = table1.Key

                            // plus about 50 other property setters
                          }).Distinct().ToList();
```

I'm trying to figure out how to refactor the property setters in the `select new MyClass() {}` expression into something more usable/readable. I've already created mappings that other classes use to map the same properties, so I'd like to be able to leverage my existing methods. Something like

```
select new MyClass() 
{
    // Existing mapping method
    MapProperties()
}
```

Is this possible? The reason for this is that I've been asked to write no SQL. Using SQL would make everything much easier.

Comment: My suggestion is to do all of that LINQ join'ing as an actual SQL view. Then map a POCO/entity to that View. Then you can just have your `MyClass` ready to go instead of having to re-write the JOIN's every time.

Comment: Select is just a function. As long as your function matches the signature of the select function you can just replace it with your own and do the mapping inside of it.

Comment: I'll edit the question to include this, but my current limitation is that we've been asked not to write any SQL at all (SPs, views, etc)

Comment: @StephenBrickner Not in an EF query you can't.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating your `MyClass` from the same classes (`Table1`, `Table2`, `Table3`), you can create an `Expression<Func<CustomTable123, MyClass>>` that does the translation for you.

---

#### Setup an intermediate container

```
public class CustomTable123
{
  public Table1 Table1 { get; set; }
  public Table2 Table2 { get; set; }
  public Table3 Table3 { get; set; }
```

#### Create a translation expression

```
public static Expression<Func<CustomTable123, MyClass>> TranslateExp = 
  x => new MyClass
  {
    propertyA = x.Table1.Key,
    ...
  } 
}
```

#### Change your query to project to your new container

```
var query = from table1 in context.Table1
            join table2 in context.Table2 on table1.Key equals table2.Key
            join table3 in context.Table3 on table1.FK equals table3.Key
            select new CustomTable123
            {
              Table1 = table1,
              Table2 = table2,
              Table3 = table3
            };
```

#### Use your expression to do all the mappings

```
List<MyClass> myClasses = query.Select(CustomTable123.TranslateExp).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you pass table1, table2 and table3 to a MyClass constructor and do your property setting in there?
If you can't touch MyClass than a factory pattern to return a newed up MyClass with properties set might be appropriate.

i.e.

```
List<MyClass> myClasses = (from table1 in context.Table1
                      join table2 in context.Table2
                      on table1.Key equals table2.Key
                      join table3 in context.Table3
                      on table1.FK equals table3.Key
                      select new MyClass(table1, table2, table3)                         
                      ).Distinct().ToList();
```

or

```
List<MyClass> myClasses = (from table1 in context.Table1
                      join table2 in context.Table2
                      on table1.Key equals table2.Key
                      join table3 in context.Table3
                      on table1.FK equals table3.Key
                      select MyFactory.MakeMyClass(table1, table2, table3)                         
                      ).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: EF won't be able to translate this into SQL appropriately.  It'll fail when you try to execute this.

Comment: The ToList() prior to the select

Comment: You need to project the joins into *something*.  You can't just project it into nothing.

Comment: can you project into an anonymous object? (I'm used to the other syntax where I can just throw a ToList() in)

Comment: The whole point of the question is how to avoid explicitly mapping all of the properties, so your solution of explicitly mapping all of the properties doesn't help.

Comment: you don't need to explicitly map all of the properties - just Table1, Table2 and Table3 into an object (anonymous or otherwise)

Answer (score -2):

> ...expression into something more usable/readable.

Create a constructor which localizes the business logic needed:

```
public Class MyClass
{

   public MyClass(table1Class  t1Entity, table2Class t2Entity, table3Class t3Entity)
   {
      // Initialize/map the incoming the class instances
      propertyA = t1Entity.Key;
      ...
   }
}
```

Then the `Select`'s projection (*that is what a select does, **it** projects from one type to another*) becomes easier to read/use

```
 ...                     
 on table1.FK equals table3.Key
 select new MyClass(table1, table2, table3){}).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: EF won't be able to translate this into SQL appropriately.  It'll fail when you try to execute this.

Comment: @Servy no problem, just change the `IQueryable` to an `IEnumerable` via `ToList()` is one option and EF/Linq To SQL will oblige.

Comment: You're then performing lots of operations on the client that ought to be performed on the DB, and pulling lots and lots of data that isn't needed from  your DB to your application.  That's a *huge* cost here.

Comment: @Servy, "You're..."?  I am just answering the question....I personally would create a stored proc to do the dirty work. *Don't shoot the answerer for answering a question* when the OP has defined the condition of not doing anything plausible/reasonable.

Comment: You provided an answer that does nothing but throw an exception, and in response to that you've suggested that the OP should do something that does something radically different from what he's asking, and that is going to have *serious* problems as a result.  If you don't have a reasonable answer then *don't post an answer*, rather than complaining when someone points out that your answer is completely broken.